# C Programming - Bitwise operators and knowing when to utilize

Tags: c, udp, hex, packet, bit

I have read in the K&R II C Programming ANSI C book that the ">>" and "<<" operators control bits, and of course with me being a noob, I don't understand when to use them. I got interested in figuring out how to build packets manually and I came across the following snippet:

```
unsigned short csum(unsigned short *buf, int nwords)
{       
        unsigned long sum;
        for(sum=0; nwords>0; nwords--)
                sum += *buf++;
        sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum &0xffff);
        sum += (sum >> 16);
        return (unsigned short)(~sum);
}
```

I know that this calculates the checksum, but I don't understand what is going on here. XD

Obviously this is out of my skill range, but I figured I can use this snippet as a scapegoat to figure out some unanswered questions. *When* do you know when to use the bitwise operators to achieve a certain value, why not just add (+) or subtract (-)? Also, why is there a hexadecimal `&0xffff` there next to `sum`, if there are no operators with the two?

P.S. What does `~sum` mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not *a* question, that's a whole bunch. :)

1. You use bitwise operators when you want to view a number as a collection of bits, rather than an integer. It's much easier to say "I want this bit-pattern shifted two bits to the left" than to create the mathematically equivalent operation. They're conceptually different; if you think of the number as bits, using a bit-operator makes *more* sense.
2. The `& 0xffff` makes sure the value is 16 bits, by masking off all higher bits. This assumes the system's `unsigned long` is at least 16 bits wide, which is a pretty safe assumption. The `&` (bitwise `AND`) is often used for this purpose. Look at the [truth table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Logical_conjunction) for logical conjunction and think "false is 0, true is 1" to see how this works.
3. The `&` before the hexadecimal constant is C's bitwise AND operator, which is used to do the masking I describe above. Basically, for single-bit variables `a & b`, the result is `1` if and only if both `a` and `b` are 1. The operator applies this logic to each pair of bits in its input terms.
4. The `~` operator is C's bitwise inversion, it "flips" the bits of its argument. It is commonly used to create masks.

Comment: Why does the hex have the `&` infront of it? If I were to remove it, what would that mean to the program?

Comment: @Ken The author of the code just omitted the space between the operator `&` and the hex-literal. Whitespace is not always necessary to separate tokens from each other, this is such a case. If you removed it, it wouldn't compile anymore because there's no operator between the two operands.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you're talking about has to do with operations on the bit level. For example "var >> num" shifts the var to the right by num (meaning it devides the var by 2^num). Also the ~var inverts the var at bit level (eg. if var = 5 in bit notation= 101 ----> ~var = 010)

Comment: So, all of the 1's become 0's and vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

> When do you know when to use the bitwise operators to achieve a certain value

Use bitwise operators when you need to operate on individual bits of an object, and simple integer arithmetic would either not be sufficient, or would less clearly describe the intent of the code.

I know this sounds facile, but it really as simple as that.

> why is there a hexadecimal `&0xffff` there next to `sum`

`&` is the bitwise-and operator.  In this case, it's used to achieve a [bitmask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29).

> What does `~sum` mean?

`~` is the bitwise-inverse operation; it inverts the value of each bit.

I would hope that each of these operators is explained in whatever book you're using to learn C.

Comment: But why is arithmetic not used in this case? What does it mean to the program?

Comment: @Ken: I don't know how to answer that.  The nature of the calculation pretty much requires bitwise operations.